# VMWare Workstation VM not starting because of locked portion of file

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am receiving the message:

> The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
>
> Cannot open the disk 'C:\Users\t825665\VM's\VPC\Windows 10 x64.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.
>
> Module 'Disk' power on failed.
>
> Failed to start the virtual machine.

So the virtual machine is not starting anymore, how to fix that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I just found the solution for this issue. I created a backup and moved the 'lck' files from my VM's directory (*.lck), removing them from the VM's directory. Then just restarted the virtual machine.

Comment: It is unnessary to do backup if it is 80 GB VM. Maybe only backup `.lck` files before delete them

Comment: I only remove the folder end with lck and its work

Comment: Vmware ask to you "are you copied or moved your files ? " when first boot after delete *.lck folder. I click "i copied" button. Then i using virtual machine without any problem.

Comment: someone know main reason of lock files??
because it's happen too often

Answer (score 16):

To solve this error, please go to virtual O's directory and delete every thing with an ".lck" extension.

Comment: Any way to script this?  My thought is something like if the IP address of the virtual doesn't ping, delete all references to files and folders with the .lck extension.

Answer (score 8):

removing folders with an extension of lck solved the issue for me

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

I run the batch file below to delete all temporary files , locks, directories and memory files in the VMWare Working Directory (i.e. Settings/Options/Working Directory). It's got me out of many a jam. You will lose any unsaved work that was in VMWare suspended memory so backup before using if you're not sure.  It will reboot the image as if it was shutdown.

--------------------------Clean.bat ----------------

```
@echo off

REM  - Delete all directories in Working Directory
set dr=%cd%
set ex=\*
set "dr=%dr%%ex%"
for /d %%a in ("%dr%") do rd "%%a" /q /s  

REM - Delete files in Working Directory
del *.log
del *.vmem
del *.vmss
del *.nvram
del *.vmx~
pause
```

Comment: Doing a version of this let me force power down a suspended virtual machine.  I just went to the VM directory and did the del commands for *.log, *.vmem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Workstation shut down, delete any *.lck files and folders in the VM folder.  Then reopen the Workstation, load the VM, and power on.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it helped, that I started the VM with admin privileges.